# How to create a new conda env based on a yml file but with different Python version

Tags: python, yaml, version, conda, environment

I have a conda environment with `python=3.6.0` and all it's dependencies. Now I would like to use this yaml file to create another environment with the same dependencies but with `python=3.7.0` without the need for installing the packages with right version one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
# Activate old environment
conda activate so
# Save the list of package to a file:
conda list > log
# Extract the package name but not the version or hash
cat log | awk '{print $1}' > log2
# make the list of packages
tr '\n' ' ' < log2 > log3
# print the list of packages
cat log3
```

Use notepad to replace `python` by `python==3.7`. Then create a new environment with the edited list of packages.

```sh
conda create --name so2
conda activate so2
conda install _libgcc_mutex ... python==3.7 ... zstd
```

Conda will try to install all packages with the same name but different version.

Comment: Thank you @Crawl Cycle. What you mentioned is a way to create the list of all packages without their version use to install them on new env, and it should work. I am still wondering if there is any more standard way around this process.

Answer (score 6):

1. Export a minimal version of the environment:

   ```bash
   conda env export -n old_env --from-history > env.yaml
   ```
2. In the `dependencies` list of the YAML there should be a `python` entry, if not you can add one. Edit it to have the Python version you want.
3. Create the new environment:

   ```bash
   conda env create -n new_env -f env.yaml
   ```

Comment: @CrawlCycle did you use the `--from-history` flag? Well, I guess I should qualify that this assumes the environment was created in a "typical" way, where user specified the handful of end requirements. If you used your answer's code to create the environment, then the environment's explicit specifications are going to include every single package.